# Como quitar el espacio en blanco en impresion con impresora termica SRP-350iii?

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

El archivo es un pdf que mando a imprimir a la impresora termica, pero me genera un espacio en blanco en la parte superior y no se como quitarlo, ya le movi a las propiedades de la impresora y nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo lo genero con PDFDOM, con estilos de una vista blade.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código de blade, quizq necesites un metatag de viewport